# aapt command not detected as an internal command while running it from a batch file in program from eclipse

Tags: batch-file, command-line, command-prompt, aapt

i have a batch file

```
CALL pushd D:\ACS\Paytm.apk
aapt dump badging "Paytm.apk"
echo Extractor is running
```

When i am running it separately I am getting output and the aapt command is running

But when I execute the same bat file from eclipse program I am getting the following error

> D:\Harish Shared\Eclipse Luna>CALL pushd D:\ACS\eBay_3.0.0.19.apk
>
> D:\ACS\eBay_3.0.0.19.apk>aapt dump badging "eBay_3.0.0.19.apk" 
> 'aapt' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
> D:\ACS\eBay_3.0.0.19.apk>echo Extractor is running 
> Extractor is running

I am sure that my path is correct and its executing the same batch file as we can see that it is changing the directory above , but why aapt command is not detected internally in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

The executable `aapt` needs to be in the current directory `D:\ACS\eBay_3.0.0.19.apk` or on the `path` for windows to find it.

You could provide the complete path, ie

```
"d:\wherever\aapt executable\is\aapt" dump badging "Paytm.apk"
```

Also `call push` is highly unusual. What are you attempting to do there? I'd suggest removing the `call` keyword.

Comment: Thanks Magoo for your suggestion. aapt command is set in path variable so aapt is running from command prompt externally irrespective of any path. Even the batch file in that path is running when i double click it . But while running it from eclipse it is not running its saying aapt not recignized . On other system the same project is running fine . do u have any idea why this is occuring from eclipse

Comment: I am using call push because the "Paytm.apk" file is in that directory. So i need to go in that directory first and then fire the aapt dump badging "Paytm.apk" command on that apk file to get results.

Comment: Pushd is adequate. `call` executes a subroutine (which may be an executable) and returns to the instruction following the `call` when that subroutine is finished. `pushd` saves the current directory on a stack and moves to the destination directory specified. When a `POPD` is executed, the saved directory is popped back from the stack and the original directory is restored as current.